# Scribe java error while using Twitter Streaming Api

Tags: java, maven, twitter, scribe, twitter-streaming-api

**import error**

[image: import statements not working]

**console error**

Failed to execute goal on project streamingTwitter: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.mycompany:streamingTwitter:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.scribe:scribe:jar:1.3.4, org.spark:spark:jar:0.9.9.4-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find org.scribe:scribe:jar:1.3.4 in http://maven.springframework.org/release was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of spring-maven-release has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

***pom.xml***

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"                        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
        <artifactId>streamingTwitter</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>jar</packaging>
        <properties>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-        8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
            <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
            <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        </properties>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>spring-maven-release</id>
                <name>Spring Maven Release Repository</name>
                <url>http://maven.springframework.org/release</url>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
        <dependencies>

                    <dependency>
                <groupId>com.github.scribejava</groupId>
                <artifactId>scribejava-apis</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.scribe</groupId>
                <artifactId>scribe</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.4</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.spark</groupId>
              <artifactId>spark</artifactId>
              <version>0.9.9.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </project>
```

***i'm following this tutorial
http://www.jeffkuchta.com/Tutorial/2013/02/21/java--twitter-public-streams-with-support-from-heroku-spark--oauth/.
Thanks for any help,wasted a lot of time before coming here.***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason version `1.3.4` is not in [Maven repository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scribe/scribe), try to use higher version, e.g: `1.3.5` for now.

Since the article was written, scribe has gone long way. I suggest you to get familiar with it on [ScribeJava home on Github](https://github.com/scribejava/scribejava).  All examples are [here](https://github.com/scribejava/scribejava/tree/master/scribejava-apis/src/test/java/com/github/scribejava/apis/examples), including Twitter one.

Good luck!

Comment: Twitter example helped me.https://github.com/scribejava/scribejava/blob/master/scribejava-apis/src/test/java/com/github/scribejava/apis/examples/TwitterExample.java

Comment: And Please mark the question up,if you think it shows some research and can help others.thanks